# Difference between control space and non-breaking space

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

In my answer to [Two-column layout with left column just as wide as its content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59239/how-can-i-get-following-layout) I've used non-breaking spaces `~` (ties) to align monospaced text. Actually I rather meant control spaces `\` , but they're less convenient to type (and read), and line breaks were not of interest anyway. Some experiments concerning line breaking are documented in the code below.

**Question**: Besides their line-breaking behaviour, is there any difference between `\`  and `~`? In particular, do (or may) they *by nature* have a different width?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[75]

%non-breaking space
lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
lorem lorem lo~lo~lo~lo~lo~lo~lo~lo~ip~ip~ip~sum sum sum sum sum sum sum sum sum

lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
lorem lorem lo~lo~lo~lo~lo~ %input line break doesn't affect non-breaking space
lo~lo~lo~ip~ip~ip~sum sum sum sum sum sum sum sum sum

lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
lorem lorem lo~lo~lo~lo~lo  %breaks at input line break
lo~lo~lo~ip~ip~ip~sum sum sum sum sum sum sum sum sum

%breaks at protected space
lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
lorem lorem lo~lo~lo~lo~lo\ lo~lo~lo~ip~ip~ip~sum sum sum sum sum sum sum sum sum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Control space `\` and a tie `~` have the same width and only differ in their line-breaking behaviour. The definition of the latter, taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) is:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nobreakspace}{%
   \leavevmode\nobreak\ }
\catcode `\~=13
\def~{\nobreakspace{}}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why it's _LaTeX_ that defines the tie. Is it not a TeX primitive?

Comment: @dgs: Yes, TeX actually defines it as `\penalty\@M\ `, but LaTeX redefines it.

Comment: @Werner `~` is not a primitive in plain TeX, it is an active character with a macro definition (`\penalty\@M\ `, as you say).

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the difference... What do they do different then?

Comment: @Tvde1: They differ in how things happen around a line-break. `~` inserts a large penalty while `\ ` does not. Does [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/L0uSzUcS) explain it better?

Comment: Alright, `\ ` does not add a penalty and `~` does. Many thanks!